# How to query realm db to obtain relevant data for each day based on stored timestamp?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

This is how my model look like

```
class Run: Object {
  dynamic var duration:Double = 0
  dynamic var elevation:Double = 0.0
  dynamic var distance:Double = 0.0
  dynamic var filePathString:String = ""
  dynamic var exported:Bool = false
  dynamic var timestamp:Date = Date()
  let locations = List<Location>()

}
```

List of runs is presented in tableView, where each header denotes the exact date (for instance 10/10/2016).

Is it possible to construct realm query to obtain relevant runs for each day?

To be clear, I want to achieve something like this

```
let isSameDay = Calendar.current.isDate(date1, inSameDayAs: date2)
```

using Realm queries.

Comment: Are you just wanting the records for a range of date/times? ie. `date1>=date2 and date1<date3`, where date2 is start of day, and date3 is the start of the next day?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Realm lets you perform queries using Apple's `NSPredicate` formatting. In this particular case, it should be able to use the `BETWEEN` syntax to check which dates are within a specific slice of time, specifically between the timestamp representing the start of a day, as well as the end.

```
let calendar = NSCalendar(identifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)

let components = NSDateComponents()
components.year = 2016
components.month = 10
components.day = 10
components.hour = 0
components.minute = 0
components.second = 0

// Get the start date
let startDate = calendar?.dateFromComponents(components)

// Get the end date
components.day = 11
let endDate = calendar?.dateFromComponents(components)

// Query for the runs between these two dates
let runDates = realm.objects(Run.self).filter("timestamp BETWEEN {%@, %@}", startDate, endDate)
```

*(`NSDateComponents` code stolen from http://nshipster.com/nsdatecomponents/)*

Comment: I obtain `'Invalid value', reason: 'NSArray objects must be of type date for BETWEEN operations'`

Comment: Hmm, looking at the Realm source code (https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/master/Realm/RLMQueryUtil.mm#L581), that would imply your `startDate` and `endDate` values both aren't `NSDate` objects. Can you please double check they're both being generated correctly?

Comment: got it working, it was my fault. thanks for your help :)